# Why the function cv2.HoughLinesP() has different effects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I learn in this [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html?highlight=houghlinesp).

**This is the original picture：**
[image]

**My test code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread( 'E:/image/sudoku.png' )
gray = cv2.cvtColor( img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
edges = cv2.Canny( gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3 )
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP( edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap )
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line( img,( x1,y1 ),( x2,y2 ),( 0,255,0 ),2 )
cv2.imwrite( 'E:/image/myhoughlinesp.jpg',img )
cv2.imshow( '1',img )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**The result of my code running：**
[image]

**But the picture generated by the official website is like this：**
[image]

**If you don't change the code.(Use that link's code),the generated picture is like this:**
[image]

When I change the code, although there are a lot of green lines,but doesn't have the official website's good effect.

Why do I have a different picture from the official website?

Comment: you run a different code. The line `for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:` was changed by you to `for line in lines:     for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:`

Comment: @CIsForCookies Sorry,if you do it like that link,you can just see one green line.

Comment: It is hard for me to reproduce the site's exact output - but I'm pretty sure that if you play with the thresholds you should get there

Comment: Or if you would like - official documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html

Comment: @Dmitrii Z. Thank you!But I think the effect is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I know why the effect is different.**

**The function cv2.HoughLinesP() in python3.X has 7 parameters.**

```
def HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold, lines=None, minLineLength=None, maxLineGap=None):
```

**But the code of the official website only writes 6 parameters.So you should write the name of the parameter,like this:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread( 'E:/image/sudoku.png' )
gray = cv2.cvtColor( img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
edges = cv2.Canny( gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3 )
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP( edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=maxLineGap )
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line( img,( x1,y1 ),( x2,y2 ),( 0,255,0 ),2 )
cv2.imwrite( 'E:/image/myhoughlinesp.jpg',img )
cv2.imshow( '1',img )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Result picture:**

[image]