# Python opencv probabilistic Hough line transform - TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

I wanted to perform a probabilistic Hough line transform on a checkerboard image, but ran into an error. A weird thing about this error is that **it only occurs when I specify keywords for the arguments of the OpenCV function HoughLinesP()**.

First, check out my code lines and the error message I got:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8-*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

# Load image file
fpath = 'D:/Users/'
image = io.imread(fpath + 'checkerboard.JPG')
image_original = image.copy()

edges = cv2.Canny(image, 50, 200, apertureSize=3)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 0
# Perform the probabilistic Hough transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[i]:
        cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=150)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(image_original, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

plt.show()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\sihohan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-c2c4eb0ac4e8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Users/2_prob_hough.py', wdir='D:/Users')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/Users/2_prob_hough.py", line 20, in <module>
    for i in range(len(lines)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

As mentioned above, my code works fine if I don't specify the keywords for the arguments of HoughLinesP():

```
# Perform the probabilistic Hough transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
```

What could be the reason for this?
Thank you.

(Below are the output images for maxLineGap = 0, 10, and 20)

- maxLineGap = 0:
  [checkerboard_maxLineGap_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Gi8.png)
- maxLineGap = 10:
  [checkerboard_maxLineGap_10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rib0k.png)
- maxLineGap = 20:
  [checkerboard_maxLineGap_20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nxJx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV houghLinesP parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609719/opencv-houghlinesp-parameters) states that `cv2.HoughLinesP` contains the redundant parameter `lines`. So your minLineLength in

```
# Perform the probabilistic Hough transform
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
```

is used as `lines` parameter. Therefore `maxLineGap` is used as `minLineLength` yielding more results given that it is set to zero.

Comment: Yes, so I figured it would work if I specified all the parameters (image=, rho=, theta=, threshold=, minLineLength=, maxLineGap=), but I noticed that I need to specify all of them except for `image=` as suggested in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609719/opencv-houghlinesp-parameters), which is also weird...So if I write `lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)`, my code works, but this time, the problem is that it only works when maxLineGap is not 0. Would you happen to know the reason for this?

Comment: My first guess would be, that you don't have lines satisfying all parameters in your image, but I can't say for sure. Can you upload your image?

Comment: I added links to the generated output images in my post. So to be clear, for maxLineGap=0, the code worked and generated the output when I didn't specify any parameters, but for maxLineGap=10 and 20, I had to specify all the parameters except for the first one (image=).

Comment: I'm not shure if I'm getting your question right. If you peek the definition of `HoughTranformP` you see `def HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold, lines=None, minLineLength=None, maxLineGap=None):`. If you don't specify parameters and use your code as above you use the `lines` parameter and `maxLineGap` is 0 per default. Did you try only specifying `maxLineGap` and `minLineLength`? That should work too.

Comment: I tried only specifying `maxLineGap` and `minLineLength` as you suggested, and this works only for `maxLineGap` of 10 and 20, but not for 0. If I don't specify the parameters at all, it works for all `maxLineGap` values (0, 10, and 20), but I assume the output I get is wrong, because I would be using `minLineLength` as `lines`, and `maxLineGap` as `minLineLength` as you pointed out. But if you take a look in here [link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html), they use HoughLinesP() without specifying any parameters...

Comment: As it is stated here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496032/why-the-function-cv2-houghlinesp-has-different-effects), I think the correct way to use `HoughLinesP()` is indeed by specifying at least the parameters `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap`, but this hasn't been working for `maxLineGap=0`. I tried using a different theta value(`theta=np.pi/360` instead of `theta=np.pi/180`), and this somehow works, but the resulting image is of course different from the one I included in my post. Still quite confused...